# Getting subdirectory with regex for snippet

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, transform

To create a snippet in vscode that returns the name of a file I use:

```
{$TM_FILENAME}
```

To create a snippet in vscode that returns the name of a directory with its first capital letter I use:

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/.*\\/(.*)$/${1:/capitalize}/g}
```

But I need to get a subdirectory and leave all the letters in lowercase. For example,

```
a/b/c/d/e
```

how could i get the \d directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
"LowercaseFolderPath": {
    "scope": "",
    "prefix": "lowercasefolderpath",
    "body": [
       "${TM_DIRECTORY/([^\\/\\\\]+)(?=[\\/\\\\][^\\/\\\\]*$)/${1:/downcase}/}"
    ],
    "description": "Lower-case folder path"
    },
```

Here, `([^\/\\]+)(?=[\/\\][^\/\\]*$)` regex captures the last but one subdirectory into `$1`, and the `${1:/downcase}` replacement turns it to lower case.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wwu6Ou/1).